# NSWorkspace `icon(forFileType:` returning default icon

Tags: macos, appkit, nsimage, nsworkspace

The docs for `NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFileType:` state:

```
/* 
 * Get the icon for a given file type.
 *
 * The file type may be a filename extension, or a HFS code encoded via NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode, or a Universal Type Identifier (UTI).
 *
 * Returns a default icon if the operation fails.
 *
 */

// Swift
open func icon(forFileType fileType: String) -> NSImage

// Objective-C
- (NSImage *)iconForFileType:(NSString *)fileType;
```

Note:

> **Returns a default icon if the operation fails.**

How can you tell if the operation has "failed" and a default icon is being returned?

Is there a way to determine if you're getting a default icon back *without* doing an expensive Image or Data comparison?

Comment: `kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon` spotlight index [via the `mdls` command line tool](https://superuser.com/questions/209145/how-to-get-a-files-uti-from-the-command-line-in-mac-os-x) might be a key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick test, it looks like when `iconForFileType` fails, it returns the same pointer every time. That makes sense, because it probably just interns a single, shared reference to that "no file type" image.

So, you could grab that pointer once, with a known-unknown file type:

```
// Do this once, at program startup for example, and keep the reference
NSImage* x = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:@".this_is_not_a_file_type"];
```

Then just do a pointer comparison:

```
NSImage* y = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:@".xxx"];
NSLog(@"%p %p", x, y);

if (x == y)
    // `iconForFileType` failed
```

Comment: I had tried this... I was comparing to the pointer to the icon for `"public.item"`, which is the base UTI and returns the "default" icon... but that icon pointer **does not** equal an "unknown" file type's pointer. But if, like in your answer, I set my control icon to be a random/bad file type (rather than `"public.item"`) the equality does then work!

Comment: Spoke a bit too soon on this. Like `public.item`, other UTIs / file types such as `public.image` also return *unique references* to the same default icon. So I'm going to have to add some kind of de-duping process in addition to the pointer comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

NSWorkspace extension to instead return `nil` if the `icon(forFileType:` operation fails:

```
extension NSWorkspace {

    func iconOptional(forFileType fileType: String) -> NSImage? {
        let icon = self.icon(forFileType: fileType)
        let iconDefault = self.icon(forFileType: "") // "Returns a default icon if the operation fails."
        return icon === iconDefault ? nil : icon
    }

}
```